# How to find backup vaults for an Azure blob container and file share using AZ CLI

Tags: containers, command-line-interface, backup, vault, fileshare

I'm working on an automation project where I need to find the backup vaults configured for blob container and file share. I searched Microsoft documents but couldn't find anything to achieve my goal. Could anyone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/dataprotection/backup-instance?view=azure-cli-latest#az-dataprotection-backup-instance-list-from-resourcegraph(dataprotection)):
AZ command:

```
az dataprotection backup-instance list-from-resourcegraph --datasource-type AzureBlob --datasource-id
```